# How to do a redirection with Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I need your help...
I'm learning flask and I have a problem, when I click on submit on my form I'd like to redirect the user to another route but I can `return` only 1 thing in so I'd to know how to do this ?
Here's my code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect
from text import text
from art import * #tprint()
from config import config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config)


@app.route('/', methods=['get', 'post'])
def transformer():
    form = text()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        fichier = open('texts.txt', 'w')
        a = form.text.data
        fichier.write(str(a))
        fichier.close()
        print(True)
    return render_template("index.html", title = "Transformateur de texte !", form=form)

@app.route('/resultat')
def afficher():
   fichier = open('texts.txt', 'r')
   word = fichier.readline()
   fichier.close()
   return render_template("render.html", title="Résultat", text_final = tprint(word))
```

line 17, I'd like to redirect my user if the form is good to afficher(), how to do this please ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to flask too but I have been achieving this desired result using the flask redirect() function.

```
from flask import redirect
```

you can now pass the url_for ( ) method as an arguement, specifying the route to which you want to redirect the user

An example from my own project

```
return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

see https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/ for more information

Sorry, I re read your question. You may achieve the desired result using a structure similar to that below

```
def transformer():
 form = text()
 if form.validate_on_submit():
     fichier = open('texts.txt', 'w')
     a = form.text.data
     fichier.write(str(a))
     fichier.close()
     print(True)
     return redirect(url_for('home')
 return render_template("index.html", title = "Transformateur de texte !", form=form)
```

Comment: I want to show my first âge with my form then when I complete the form and click on the button, it redirects me on the 2nd page that's why I don't know how to do it. By the way the ``` return redirect(url_for('home')) ``` doesn't worked :/

Comment: @pepitoo999 As my basic understanding goes within the if form.validate_on_submit(): block you will perform your file operations as in this case and then you will perform a redirect to your desired route. After you exit this context block then you will render your template. Are you sure you are passing the correct route to the url_for ( ) function ? If you post the error message you are receiving I may be of more help.

Comment: It gives me no error that's the problem, it just reload my '/' page

Comment: what if I put a <a href=""> in my html like this ``` <a href = {{ redirect(url_for('afficher") }} > {{ form.submit(class="form-input")}} </a> ?

Comment: @pepitoo999 An html element will only affect the presentation of the page. If you wish to perform an automatic redirect upon form validation it would have to be done from within the route I believe. Perhaps someone with more experiece will be able to help with the matter. If I was you I would just ensure that you are passing the correct route to the url_for ( ) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `redirect("/your/url")` to redirect to another already existing site.